# Parse.com constraint "whereNotStartsWith"

Tags: android, parse-platform, constraints

I want to exclude urls that start with https, is there a way to do this with the Parse.com query constraints?

The docs on whereStartsWith

```
[https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereStartsWith(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep your links as `Strings` in Parse you probably should be able to call (on your `ParseQuery` object):

```
query.whereStartsWith(KEY_TO_FIELD_STORING_LINK, "http://");
```

if the field stores a value that starts with `https://` it won't be returned as a result of this `ParseQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/M_Parse_ParseQuery_1_WhereDoesNotMatchesKeyInQuery__1.htm), this should work:

```
    ParseObject.GetQuery("yourClassName")
           .WhereDoesNotMatchesKeyInQuery("yourUrlKey", "yourUrlKey",
           ParseObject.GetQuery("yourClassName").WhereStartsWith("yourUrlKey", "https"));
```